# Did the Jesus Revolution produce lasting Christian "Fruit", or was it an emotional, fadish "flash in the pan?

Tags: ecclesiology, conversion, youth, revival, jesus-movement

Amidst the 70s War protests, Feminist "bra burning, Sexual revolution, Hippie rebellion, New Age infusion, and Drug abuse, there arose the **Jesus Revolution** movement!  Instead of going along with the cultural motto, *Tune in, turn on, drop out*, there were heard shouts of *Praise the Lord!* and worship singing accompanied with guitars, in the city parks--as well as baptisms in the fountains! The phenom took over America so much that the **Face of Jesus** even made it on the cover of TIME magazine!

So, was this all just an adjunct to the hippie culture of the 70s, or was it a genuine break-away movement that became a life of its own? And since it was Christian based, did it benefit Christianity by producing lasting commitments to the principles of the Christian religion? That is, was there:

- a rise in church attendance
- increase in spiritual worship
- more charitable giving
- unity among the church family
- establishment of new church congregations
- respect for the older generation
- change in moral life-style
- greater desire to do Bible study
- established prayer life

Was this movement a genuine, religiously beneficial phenomenon for the Christian Church? Were existing denominations edified, as well as new congregations created that enlarged the Kingdom of God? What do the registry documents of denominations reveal concerning new membership?

Comment: I’m voting to close this contribution because it is a rant and not an academically based question.

Comment: @NigelJQuestions cannot be classified as "rant." Revivals are a major part of Christianity! This was one of them, like the Great Awakening, or the Azusa revival of Kentucky, or the Toronto Blessing. Why cannot it be scrutinized, annalized,  examined for its benefits, etc.  Theologians would find it a worthy subject for research for future reference concerning future revivals.

Comment: This is anecdotal, so not an answer, but my own impression from the time was that it was mostly just a hippie offshoot based on (usually wrong) perceptions of Jesus as a human. He had long hair and loose flowing clothing, he advocated peace and harmony, disrespected authority, and of course he and the disciples lived day-to-day in a communal world; so what was there for them not to like? Most saw this fictional Jesus as an ideal human (made in *their* image),  while caring little about what his actual message was. Not a lot different from Maharishi Mahesh Yogi and Transcendental Mediation.

Comment: (Hippie Jesus) It is true that there were physical aspects of Jesus that the American hippies related to...which may have been inaccurate.  BUT they were not anywhere in the same classification as the Oriental and New Age cults that swept America. Jesus People accepted "salvation only by faith in the redemptive sacrifice of Jesus on the cross!"  They lived by the message of the N.T. Gospel often fanatically, with passion. They accepted the Trinity aspect of Godhood, unlike the Oriental religions.  And they did not "meditate" on themselves, but on the Scriptures (Psalm 119), different from TM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calvary_Chapel_Association), in 2022 Calvary Chapel Association had some 1800 churches.

> The association has its origins in the founding of a Calvary Chapel Costa Mesa (California) in 1965 by pastor Chuck Smith of the International Church of the Foursquare Gospel with 25 people. In 1968 they broke away from Foursquare Church. Prior to Smith, Costa Mesa members spoke of their own vision of becoming part of a massive church movement.

> In **1969 Calvary Chapel became a hub in what later became known as the Jesus movement** when Smith's daughter introduced him to her boyfriend John Higgins Jr., a former hippie who had become a Christian, and who went on to head the largest Jesus freak movement in history, the Shiloh Youth Revival Centers (1968-1989). John Higgins introduced Smith to Lonnie Frisbee, the "hippie evangelist" who became a key figure in the growth of both the Jesus Movement and Calvary Chapel. Frisbee moved into Smith's home, and he would minister to other hippies and counter-culture youth on the beaches. At night he would bring home new converts, and soon Smith's house was full. Frisbee became leader in a rental home for the steadily growing crowd of Christian hippies and he named the commune "House of Miracles"; other Houses of Miracles would develop throughout California and beyond. As Calvary Chapel grew "explosively", a tent was erected during the construction of a new building.

> The converts included musicians who began writing music for praise and worship. This became the genesis for Jesus music and Christian rock concerts. Maranatha! Music eventually formed to publish and promote the music. The services led by Frisbee usually resembled rock concerts more than any worship services of the time. Frisbee featured in national television-news reports and magazines with images of him baptizing hundreds at a time in the Pacific Ocean. The network of House of Miracles communes/crash pads/coffee houses began doing outreach concerts with Smith or Frisbee preaching, Frisbee calling forth the Holy Spirit and the newly forming bands playing the music. By the early 1970s Calvary Chapel was home to ten or more musical groups that were representative of the Jesus people movement.

In 1982 John Wimber, a Calvary Chapel pastor, and the Calvary Chapel leadership mutually agreed to part ways. Tension had been mounting over Wimber's emphasis on spiritual manifestations, leading Wimber to withdraw from Calvary Chapel and to affiliate with a network of churches that would become the Association of Vineyard Churches.

Churches in the Vineyard Movement are also evangelical in nature and [orthodox in their basic doctrine](https://www.gotquestions.org/Vineyard-Movement.html). They hold to salvation by grace through faith and are very concerned with spreading the gospel of the kingdom.  The predominant differences between the two revolve around Vineyard's emphasis upon the "sign gifts" of the Spirit and experientially centered worship.  In 2022, 2400 churches were claimed to be in affiliation.

In 2012, Pastor Chuck Smith founded the Calvary Chapel Association (CCA) to unite all of the movement's churches around the world.

Today in the US (at least) Calvary Chapel preaching has a predominant spot in radio broadcasting and this preaching is consistently identified with an insistence upon the Triune nature of God, faith in Christ alone precipitating the new birth, a high view of Scripture, and the intention of preaching the whole word of God.

While there is always room for theological differences, and Chuck Smith's prediction of the 2nd coming of Christ in 1981 was certainly a tragic mistake, both the Calvary Chapel Movement and the Vineyard Movement certainly qualify as examples of the continuous bearing of the fruit of basic gospel tenets preached during the "Jesus freak" years.

Comment: I came to know the Lord in 1975 during that whole movement. It was an incredible time and worship was so spontaneous with such great music.  At that time was going to church and fellowships five days a week, the move of God's Spirit was strong.  Eventually had to learn how to walk by faith in His word alone.
That was a beginning for many who are still growing in the Grace of God.

Comment: I'd say the Vineyard churches would count as a lasting result of the Jesus people movement. You mention it in passing, but it's still a denomination that continues to exist.

Comment: @nick012000 Thanks.  I added a little something on Vineyard.